# Polar decomposition not assuming positive-semidefiniteness of the Hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, positive-semidefinite

Let $A$ be a square complex matrix. Its polar decomposition is $A=UH,$ where
$U$ is a unitary and $H$ is a positive-semidefinite Hermitian matrix (i.e. all
its eigenvalues are real not negative).

Literature says that the matrix $H$ is always unique positive-semidefinite and
given by $H=\sqrt{A^{*}A},$ where $A^{*}$ is the transpose conjugate of
$A.$ This is because $L=A^{*}A$ is a positive-semidefinite Hermitian
matrix, and therefore has a unique positive-semidefinite Hermitian square root.

I'm interested in the following question:
**Why is it always assumed the condition of positive-semidefiniteness for the
Hermitian matrix $H$?**

I mean, for example if $A$ is a $2\times2$ matrix then there are
four square roots of the matrix $L=A^{*}A$. All four roots can be obtained from
the eigenvalues $\left(  \lambda_{1},\lambda_{2}\right)  $ and eigenvectors
$\left(  v_{1},v_{2}\right)  $ of $L$. If we define the matrix
$$ S=%
\begin{bmatrix}
\pm\sqrt{\lambda_{1}} & 0\\
0 & \pm\sqrt{\lambda_{2}}%
\end{bmatrix}, $$
then the four square roots read as $H=\sqrt{A^{*}A}=VSV^{-1},$
where $V$ is the matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors $\left(
v_{1},v_{2}\right)$, and $S$ is any of the sign combinations of above matrix.

Here an example with real numbers: The matrix
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2\\
3 & 4
\end{bmatrix}, $$
can be decomposed as
$$ A = U_{1}H_{1}=%
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.5145 & 0.8575\\
0.8575 & 0.5145
\end{bmatrix}%
\begin{bmatrix}
2.0580 & 2.4010\\
2.4010 & 3.7730
\end{bmatrix}
, $$
$$ A =U_{2}H_{2}=%
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.9806 & 0.1961\\
-0.1961 & -0.9806
\end{bmatrix}%
\begin{bmatrix}
-1.5689 & -2.7456\\
-2.7456 & -3.5301
\end{bmatrix}
. $$
Eigenvalues of $H_{1}$ are $\left(  0.366,5.465\right)  $. Eigenvalues of
$H_{2}$ are $\left(  0.366,-5.465\right)  $. The first option $H_{1}$ is the
expected positive-semidefinite Hermitian matrix (both eigenvalues positive). However, it is a fact that the second option represents a different but valid polar decomposition of the matrix $A$. **Why it is ignored in the literature?**

Comment: For the same reason we require all the singular values to be nonnegative: to make the decomposition as unique as possible.

Comment: May i say that when $H\ge 0$ it is unique otherwise $UH$ is a unitary by a Hermitian, you gave $H_1$, $H_2$ etc

Comment: Thanks for answering. But  "to make the decomposition as unique as possible"  seems to be a simple reason.  I was thinking there was a more fundamental mathematical reason to ignore the second solution, because, actually the decomposition is not unique.

Comment: We are not only ignoring the second solution, of course, but also the third solution with eigenvalues $(-0.366,5.465)$, and the fourth solution with eigenvalues $(-0.366,-5.465)$. For an $n\times n$ matrix we have $2^n$ solutions from which to choose. How would you choose?